# Select records that are not associated with the other record

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, ado.net, oledb

Hi i have 3 tables `Modules`,`Students` and join table (many to many) `StudentModules`.I want to select all modules that the student has not registered for.When the student register the information is stored in the `StudentModules` table.Basically i want to select all modules that are not associated with the student number in the `StudentModules` table from the `Modules` table. 
[image]

i have tried the following code

```
SELECT Modules.*, Students.*
FROM            ((StudentsModules INNER JOIN
                     Modules ON StudentsModules.ModuleCode = Modules.ModuleCode) INNER JOIN
                     Students ON StudentsModules.StudentNo = Students.StudentNo)
                     Where StudentNo = 48377767 AND WHERE ModuleCode NOT IN (SELECT ModuleCode FROM StudentsModules)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to select all modules that the student has not registered for, assuming that the student no is `48377767` in this example :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Modules m
     LEFT JOIN StudentsModules sm ON sm.ModuleCode = m.ModuleCode 
                                     AND sm.StudentNo = 48377767
WHERE sm.ModuleCode IS NULL
```

[**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d0e6/3)**]

**UPDATE :**

Different approach without `JOIN` :

```
SELECT m.*
FROM Modules m
WHERE m.ModuleCode NOT IN
                   (
                      SELECT ModuleCode
                      FROM StudentsModules
                      WHERE StudentNo = 48377767
                    )
```

Comment: This return empty result set.

Comment: the query works in `MySql`, i'm getting `{System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException} {"JOIN expression not supported."}` in `Visual Basic`.

Comment: @Phuti posted another possible solution without using `JOIN`, try it out

Comment: all your queries work in `MySql` and my `Query Builder` but gives me an error in my code, maybe i'm missing something. thanks for you help.

Comment: there was an error in my code, i was accessing columns that where not in the results set.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, you forgot one check at the end!

Edit this part:

```
NOT IN (SELECT ModuleCode FROM StudentsModules where StudentNo=48377767)
```